# Simultaneous Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $C(\mathbb{T})$ be the Banach algebra of continuous functions on the unit circle. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $P_n(\mathbb{T})$ be the subspace of trigonometric polynomials of degree at most $n$.

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_N$ be positive linear functionals on $P_n(\mathbb{T})$. Define \begin{equation} A_{j,k} = \sup_{0 < p \in P_n(\mathbb{T})} \frac{\ell_j(p)}{\ell_k(p)}\end{equation}

Do there exist positive linear extensions $\widetilde{\ell}_1,\ldots,\widetilde{\ell}_N$  of $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_N$ to all of $C(\mathbb{T})$ such that $\widetilde{\ell}_j(f) \leq A_{j,k} \widetilde{\ell}_k(f)$ for all nonnegative $f \in C(\mathbb{T})$ and all $j,k \in \{1,\ldots,N\}$?